# High CPU % when using delegate

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I'm running the following piece of code which uses a delegate to return an asynchronous Network Stream:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NetworkStream myNetworkStream;
    Socket socket;
    IPEndPoint maxPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), xxxx);

    socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Connect(maxPort);

    myNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int offset = 0;
    int count = 1024;

    string Command = "LOGIN,,,xxxx\n";
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

    myNetworkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, new AsyncCallback(OnBeginRead), myNetworkStream);
    myNetworkStream.Write(encoder.GetBytes(Command), 0, encoder.GetByteCount(Command));

    while (true) { }
}

public static void OnBeginRead(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    NetworkStream ns = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] received = new byte[bufferSize];

    ns.EndRead(ar);

    int read;

    while (true)
    {
        if (ns.DataAvailable)
        {
            string result = String.Empty;

            read = ns.Read(received, 0, bufferSize);
            result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
            received = new byte[bufferSize];

            result = result.Replace(" ", "");
            result = result.Replace("\0", "");
            result = result.Replace("\r\n", ",");

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but my CPU usage is through the roof (50% on an Intel Core i3), so obviously I'm doing it wrong, but how so?

Thanks

Comment: The `while (true)` will never terminate and it keeps the CPU busy looping endlessly.

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do, as it's not clear. What is clear, though, is that the source of your high CPU usage is that you're using a tight infinite loop (`while(true)`).

Comment: I'm trying to return an asynchronous feed from an IP phone, the IPEndPoint is linked to the port on the call server that the phone is plugged into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only reading the very first bytes asynchronously, afterwards you end up in an infinite loop with sync read operations in your `OnBeginRead` method (which is a confusing name BTW). At the same time, those first bytes are discarded in your current code.

You need to process the data after `EndRead` (which is a function returning how many bytes were read into the buffer in this async operation), and then start another async read with `BeginRead` and return (there is no looping in the async code!).

Edited to add a sample showing how async reading would work:

```
internal class StreamHelper {
    private readonly NetworkStream stream;
    private readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    public StreamHelper(Socket socket) {
        stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
    }

    public NetworkStream Stream {
        get {
            return stream;
        }
    }

    public byte[] Buffer {
        get {
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args) {
    IPEndPoint maxPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), 100);

    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Connect(maxPort);

    StreamHelper helper = new StreamHelper(socket);
    helper.Stream.BeginRead(helper.Buffer, 0, helper.Buffer.Length, StreamReadCallback, helper);

    string Command = "LOGIN,,,xxxx\n";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Command);
    // note: the write isn't async, but should maybe be converted as well
    helper.Stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    Console.ReadLine(); // wait for a return key press
}

private static void StreamReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    StreamHelper helper = (StreamHelper)ar.AsyncState;
    // note: EndRead will throw an exception if something went wrong - you should deal with that
    int bytesRead = helper.Stream.EndRead(ar);
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        string charsRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(helper.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.Write(charsRead);
        helper.Stream.BeginRead(helper.Buffer, 0, helper.Buffer.Length, StreamReadCallback, helper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate a little? What do you mean by `there is no looping in the async code!`? Thanks Edit:Apologies, I wrote this comment before I saw your reply!

Comment: +1 for being the absolute *only* correct answer to this question.

Comment: Async means that you'll get called back whenever you need to do something. The conclusion is that you never do a spin-wait (e.g. loop until something happens). The workflow is simple: you start an async operation and forget about it. After some time, you'll get called back (either because data arrived or some error occured), at which time you process this event (the callback will be handled in a thread pool thread). If you got some data and you're expecting more, then you start another async operation and quit (!) - you'll again be called back whenever there's something to be processed - etc.

Comment: Just to add, CPU usage has plummeted from 50 to 0!

Comment: @JMK, great! Async is very efficient in regards of CPU usage, because the code (or threads) is not wasting time waiting. That said, there are a few things in async programming which need to be taken care of: your async code is running in another thread (implicit multithreading), therefore you need to take care with accessing shared data structures (especially also UI stuff or COM stuff); no thread affinity is guaranteed (therefore you cannot rely on thread-static data such as cultures or anything else which is thread-static), and exception handling is a bit more difficult. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looping continuously on the main thread:

```
while (true) { }
```

This causes the CPU core of that thread to be at full capacity at all times. Try to sleep in order to prevent the thread from taking up CPU time unnecessarily:

```
while (true) { Thread.Sleep(5000); }
```

Comment: No. `Thread.Sleep` is a band-aid. The OP needs to use the async functions as they're intended.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps replace the inefficiency of spinning the processor at the bottom of your main method from

```
while (true) { }
```

to

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Incidentally Lucero is spot on. You're moving into an infinte loop (in OnBeginRead) with the thread that calls the callback method. This feels wrong. Callbacks should be dealt with asap to let the calling thread carry on processing. Normally you would extract the data in the callback and post a signal to your own thread to process the rest. Perhaps a [TPL](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism) thread will help here.

Comment: In what way could you replace an infinite loop with a blocking call to Console.Readline...?

Comment: I was mentioning the infinite loop in OnBeginRead. Not the one in main. Here we are holding up the calling thread.